# How do I loop through two lists only iterating one at a time?

Tags: python, list, loops, iterator

Im trying to implement merge sort in python and I'd like to know what is the pythonic way of looping through two lists iterating only one of the lists each loop.

This is what I have now (using indexes)

```
def merge(array1, array2):
     final = []
     i = 0
     j = 0
     while i < len(array1) or j < len(array2):
        if array1[i] <= array2[j]:
            final.append(array1[i])
            i += 1
        elif array2[j] < array1[i]:
            final.append(array2[j])
            j += 1
        # Finished one of the arrays
        if i == len(array1):
            final.extend(array2[j:])
            break
        elif j == len(array2):
            final.extend(array1[i:])
            break
     return final
```

Thanks.

Comment: `while True:` + flow control inside the loop that handles the incrementing + a way for the code to `break`. So similar to what you are doing

Comment: This will fail since if `i >= len(array1)` but `j < len(array2)`, it will aim to fetch `array1[i]` and `array2[j]` and thus raise an indexoutofrange...

Comment: You should not make the question rely on knowledge of merge-sort. It will get more attention if you make it generic, and it won't get mixed up with bugs or corrections to the algorithm

Comment: I assume you mean how do you do the looping without using indices. Take a look at the [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) and [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) functions.

Comment: To complement @slezica's comment, you should give an [MCVE(Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure not sure your problem here is using indices, but there's a lot of unneeded code.

Firstly, we can change your initialisers to:

```
final, i, j = [], 0, 0
```

Next, if we change your `while` condition we can remove the `break`s:

```
while i < len(array1) and j < len(array2):
```

Your `elif` isn't meaningful as it will always be true, we can thus make your `if`:

```
if array1[i] <= array2[j]:
    final.append(array1[i])
    i += 1
else:
    final.append(array2[j])
    j += 1
```

And now because we're automatically breaking out of the loop we don't need the `break`s and can move the `extend`s outside:

```
def merge(array1, array2):
    final, i, j = [], 0, 0
    while i < len(array1) and j < len(array2):
        if array1[i] <= array2[j]:
            final.append(array1[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            final.append(array2[j])
            j += 1
    final.extend(array1[i:])
    final.extend(array2[j:])
    return final
```

This gives you smaller, more readable code without actually changing the way you're doing anything, that way you'll still understand it.

---

Note that we can perform:

```
final.extend(array1[i:])
final.extend(array2[j:])
```

outside the loop because one array will have contents, for example `[7,9]`, while the other will be empty(`[]`):

```
>>> final = [3,6]
>>> array1 = [3,6]
>>> array2 = [7,9]
>>> i = 2
>>> j = 0
>>> array1[i:]
[]
>>> array2[j:]
[7, 9]
>>> final.extend(array1[i:])
>>> final
[3, 6]
>>> final.extend(array2[j:])
>>> final
[3, 6, 7, 9]
```